# Why vector C is equal to vector A - B?

Tags: vectors

I'm new into multivariable calculus  and I can't help but ask myself, Why vector $\vec{C}$ is equal to $\vec{A} -\vec{B}$?

[image]

Edit: + corrected to -

Comment: Your link isn't working. Pay attention to this, or better: thype your whole question.

Comment: @KevinMoore $\hat{c} = -\hat{b} + \hat{a}$. Since both ways get you from point $C$ to point $B$, the two vectors are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stand in point A and walk $\vec{B}$ you end up in point C. Then you walk $\vec{C}$ and end up in B, the same place where you would have been, if you walked $\vec{A}$ in the beginning. 
So $$ 
\vec{B}+\vec{C}=\vec{A} \Leftrightarrow \vec{A}-\vec{B}=\vec{C} $$
 Note that the starting point doesn't matter. 
You have (by looking at the graph)
$$
\vec{A}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} 
$$
$$
\vec{B}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-2\end{pmatrix} 
$$
$$
\vec{C}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\4\end{pmatrix} 
$$
Now you can clearly see, that 
$$
\vec{A}-\vec{B}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}2\\-2\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}-1\\4\end{pmatrix} =\vec{C}\qquad 
$$

Answer (score 2):

This is not calculus, just vector algebra.

We have $a=b+c$, by the definition of vector sum (parallelogram law).

By definition of *subtraction*, $c=a-b$ exactly when $a=b+c$.